# Prove there exist a $c$ such that $f'(c) = f(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose a function $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$
and $x_0 \in (0,1) $. Prove that there exist $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c) = f(x_0)$

My attempt:

Assume $f(x_0)>0$
there exist a $c_1$ such that $f'(c_1) = \frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0} = \frac{f(x_0)}{x_0} > f(x_0)$ as $x_0 <1$ and $c_2$ such that $f'(c_2) = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1} = 0 < f(x_0)$ by Mean Value Thereom and by IVT, there exist a 
$c$ such that $f'(c) = f(x_0)$ Do the same for $f(x_0)<0$.

However, I realise that $f'$ may not necessarily be continuous which will cause IVT to not hold. What is the approach then?

Answer (score 0):

(this is more of a comment, but since I can't comment right now, I'm writing it as an answer)

The functions which satisfies the IVT property are called Darboux functions, they need not be continuous; further for any differentiable function $f$, $f'$ is a Darboux function, this is the Darboux's theorem, google it to know more about it.